# How to reuse a random letter

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to get my code to randomly generate a letter to begin each word of "zip", "zap" and "zop". A different letter should be chosen every time the code is run but each word needs to start with the same letter.

I can't seem to get it to reuse the random letter three times:

```
def generate
  puts "3... 2... 1... IMPROV: (enter any letter)"
  text = gets.chomp.upcase
  puts text + "IP, " + text + "AP, " + text + "OP!"
  puts "My turn!"
  yield
  puts g_l(1) + "IP, " + "#{g_l(1)}AP, " + "#{g_l(1)}OP!" 
end

generate do 
  def g_l(number)
    charset = Array('A'..'Z') - Array["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    Array.new(number) { charset.sample } .join
  end
end
```

What I'm aiming for:

```
Run 1: HIP, HAP, HOP!
Run 2: DIP, DAP, DOP!
Run 3: SIP, SAP, SOP!
```

What I'm getting:

```
Run 1: HIP, ZAP COP
Run 2: FIP, WAP, DOP
Run 3: RIP, TAP, BOP
```

I tried to find the result using terms like: "generating the same random letter", "reusing a random letter", "storing a random number" etc., but those searches didn't help.

Comment: Those hip-hop dudes must be glad you did not write their naming app. FIP DOP... RIP BOP...HIP COP ?!

Comment: This is actually for Big Bird's next fire album.

Answer (score 3):

You are resampling each time you use `g_l(1)`
Instead save `char = g_l(1)` and reuse the same `char`

```
def generate
    puts "3... 2... 1... IMPROV: (enter any letter)"
        text = gets.chomp.upcase
    puts text + "IP, " + text + "AP, " + text + "OP!"
    puts "My turn!"
    yield
    char = g_l(1)
    puts char + "IP, " + "#{char}AP, " + "#{char}OP!"
end

generate do
    def g_l(number)
       charset = Array('A'..'Z') - Array["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
       Array.new(number) { charset.sample } .join
    end
end
```

or make the whole thing one function that you can call:

```
def answer
    puts "3... 2... 1... IMPROV: (enter any letter)"
    text = gets.chomp[0].upcase # Should they be able to type more than one letter?
    charset = Array('A'..'Z') - Array["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    puts text + "IP, " + text + "AP, " + text + "OP!"
    puts "My turn!"
    char = charset.sample
    puts char + "IP, " + "#{char}AP, " + "#{char}OP!"
end

answer
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you're calling your character generator three times resulting in three different letters, when you really only want to call it once to get a single character you're going to use three times:

```
g_l(1) + "IP, " + "#{g_l(1)}AP, " + "#{g_l(1)}OP!"
```

Each call of `g_l(1)` results in a new letter.

For reference, here's how I'd write it:

```
LPHBT = (('A'..'Z').to_a - %w[A E I O U])

def output(c)
  '%sIP, %sAP, %sOP!' % ([c] * 3)
end

def play
  puts '3... 2... 1... IMPROV: (enter any letter)'
  # text = gets.chomp.upcase
  text = 'A'
  puts output(text)
  puts 'My turn!'

  puts output(yield)
end

play { LPHBT.sample }

# >> 3... 2... 1... IMPROV: (enter any letter)
# >> AIP, AAP, AOP!
# >> My turn!
# >> TIP, TAP, TOP!
```

Here's some of what's happening:

```
'%sIP, %sAP, %sOP!' % ([c] * 3)
```

Uses a simple format string to plug in the results of `([c] * 3)` which creates a three-element array of `c`:

```
['c'] * 3 # => ["c", "c", "c"]
```

Using `Array.new` like you are is wasting keystrokes and reducing readability.

```
('A'..'Z').to_a - %w[A E I O U] # => ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

accomplishes the same thing with a lot less noise.